# Python write to file

Tags: python, binary, ascii

I've got a little problem here.
I'm converting binary to ascii, in order to compress data.
All seems to work fine, but when I convert '11011011' to ascii and try to write it into file, I keep getting error

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xdb' in position 0: character maps to

Here's my code:

```
    byte = ""
    handleR = open(self.getInput())
    handleW = open(self.getOutput(), 'w')
    file = handleR.readlines()
    for line in file:
        for a in range(0, len(line)):
            chunk = result[ord(line[a])]
            for b in chunk:
                if (len(byte) < 8):
                    byte+=str(chunk[b])
                else:
                    char = chr(eval('0b'+byte))
                    print(byte, char)
                    handleW.write(char)
                    byte = ""
    handleR.close()
    handleW.close()
```

Any help appreciated,

Thank You

Comment: When I read "binary to ASCII" I thought you were going the other way around, i.e. `'\xdb'` to `'11011011'` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
handleR = open(self.getInput(), 'rb')
handleW = open(self.getOutput(), 'wb')
```

That will ensure you're reading and writing byte streams.  Also, you can parse binary strings without eval:

```
char = chr(int(byte, 2))
```

And of course, it would be faster to use bit manipulation.  Instead of appending to a string, you can use `<<` (left shift) and `|` (bitwise or).

EDIT: For the actual writing, you can use:

```
handleW.write(bytes([char]))
```

This creates and writes a [bytes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#bytes) from a list consisting of a single number.

EDIT 2: Correction, it should be:

```
handleW.write(bytes([int(byte, 2)]))
```

There is no need to use `chr`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I directly (with wb mode) write (str)"11011011" into file?
No I get "TypeError: can't write str to binary stream"

Comment: Thank you so much.
Final working and version is handleW.write(bytes(chr(int(byte, 2)), "utf-8"))

Comment: @Mikk, my previous answer was partly wrong.  It can just be `handleW.write(bytes([int(byte, 2)]))`.